# error CS1525: Unexpected symbol '<internal>' の意味

Tags: c#, unity3d

> Assets/Scenes/Player_NonPhysics2D.cs(42,32): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol '< internal >'

というエラーが出ますが、このエラーの意味がわかりません。指摘されている42行目とは次のコードの `return;` 行です。

```
//フレームの描き換え
void Update() {
    if(goalCheck) { //ゴールチェック
        return;　　　//ゴールだったら処理停止

    }
}
```

Comment: あなたのは回答じゃないですよね？

Comment: @user8269 この質問文だと、傍から見た時に問題を丸投げしているように見えてしまい、反対票が多くなっているものと思われます。質問する側の立場として、例えば「○○しても理由が分からなかった」とか__自分で調べたんだけど分からなかった__ という前置きは大事です。今回の場合は具体的なエラーも出力されていますし、そういった経緯はございませんか？

Comment: エラーがでてるのはわかっていても、どこの部分がエラーになっているのかが
わかりませんでした。エラー名で検索してみましたが、初心者ですのでほとんど理解できませんでした。　不快に思ったなら申し訳ありませんが、悪意のある質問と決め付けるのはやめてください。＞ぽぽたんさん

Comment: たしかに言葉足らずでした、以降気をつけたいと思います。　sironeさん

Comment: 質問にクローズ票を投じます。オフトピックである理由: 質問になっていない

Comment: 否定的なコメントを避けましょう。改善につながる具体的なアドバイスであっても、否定的にならないようにしましょう。[気持ちよく参加するために](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)を参考してください。

Answer (score 3):

少なくとも全角スペースが含まれているためにエラーが発生しています。

なおC#言語仕様では字句解析上の空白文字はUnicode クラス Zs の任意の文字と定められているため全角スペースを使用しても問題ありません。あくまでUnity固有の問題です。

Answer (score 0):

'　' (全角スペース) を検索してみたらいかがでしょうか。

42 行目、return の後に全角空白が 3 つありますね。